# Find relation between $e^x$ and $x$

Tags: calculus, functions

If I want to find out if $e^{x}$ is $<$, $>$, $\ge$, $\le$ or not comparable to $x$. I need to find out if $e^{x}-x$ is positive,negative or what? I have taken two functions here but those can pretty much be any functions.

What is the way to establish such relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard method of doing this would be to look at the derivative.
By analyzing that, you could see when the function is increasing, when it is decreasing, and therefore, find its maxima and minima, and when it is positive and negative. (At least approximately)

For example, if you were to find the function (Their difference) is positive everywhere, you'd find $e^x-x\geq0\Rightarrow e^x\geq x$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

**Step-1:** Define, $f(x)=e^x-x.$

**Step-2:** Try to find out $f'(x)$.

**Step-3:** Determine when $f'(x)$ is positive, negative or equal to zero.

**Step-4:** You will find a minima. Compute $f(x)$ value at minima. Rest I hope you could figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one approach.

For example you could say that $e^x$ is always positive so when $x \lt 0$ you have $e^x \gt 0 \gt x$ , while $e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$ so when $x \ge 0$ you have $e^x \ge 1+x \gt x$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends strongly on the functions in question. For $\exp$ and $\def\i{\mathord{\rm id}}\i$ in your example here, you can use $\exp'' = \exp > 0$, that is strong convexity of $\exp$ to gain that $\exp$ is always larger than any of its tangents (except at the touching point), or 
$$ \exp(x) > \exp(0) + x\exp'(0) = 1 + x,\qquad x \ne 0 $$
Hence $\exp(x) > x$ for all $x$.